# How can I get a basic Fortran file to compile on Windows/MinGW using CMake?

Tags: cmake, gfortran, clion

I feel completely lost trying to get CMake to work on Windows.  I have a project ([ECCODES](https://software.ecmwf.int/wiki/display/ECC/Releases)) that has Fortran and C files.  I can compile Fortran files if I don't use CMake.  But this project came with a ton of CMake files.  I look at the error below and it says to me, "*I (CMake) cannot compile a simple Fortran program even though you can compile Fortran files when you aren't using CMake."*  Can anyone make sense of this?  I'm trying to use mingw64 since I can't use cygwin on this project for the Windows build.  On Mac OS X and GNU/Linux everything builds fine, but I have to run this project on Windows...

```
Error:The Fortran compiler "c:/gcc-5.1.0-tdm64-1-fortran/bin/gfortran.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.
It fails with the following output:
 Change Dir: C:/Users/knauthg/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/ECCodes-45f4e5f3/45f4e5f3/__default__/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
Run Build Command:"C:/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_93cb8/fast"
C:/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_93cb8.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_93cb8.dir/build
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/knauthg/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/ECCodes-45f4e5f3/45f4e5f3/__default__/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building Fortran object CMakeFiles/cmTC_93cb8.dir/testFortranCompiler.f.obj
c:\gcc-5.1.0-tdm64-1-fortran\bin\gfortran.exe -c C:\Users\knauthg\.CLion2016.1\system\cmake\generated\ECCodes-45f4e5f3\45f4e5f3\__default__\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testFortranCompiler.f -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_93cb8.dir\testFortranCompiler.f.obj
CMakeFiles\cmTC_93cb8.dir\build.make:64: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_93cb8.dir/testFortranCompiler.f.obj' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_93cb8.dir/testFortranCompiler.f.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/knauthg/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/ECCodes-45f4e5f3/45f4e5f3/__default__/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:125: recipe for target 'cmTC_93cb8/fast' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [cmTC_93cb8/fast] Error 2
CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before, I was using the [`tdm-gcc`](http://tdm-gcc.dragon.net) Windows 64-bit build of `gfortran`.  I switched to the 64-bit build of `gfortran` by [Simply Fortran](http://simplyfortran.com/), and now the entire [ECCODES](https://software.ecmwf.int/wiki/display/ECC/Releases) project builds to completion using CMake.  I'm still using MingW64 `gcc` to compile the C files.

Hat tip to John Wasilewski on a [thread of Physics Forums](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/best-fortran-compiler-for-windows-7.465593/) who gave the tip about Simply Fortran.