# How do I build/compile Fortran with MinGW gfortran via CMake?

Tags: cmake, gfortran, mingw-w64, msys2, cmake-gui

I've got much more I've got to get figured out with CMake than just the following problem, but it's the first and simplest one which I still can't get past. I've scoured the interwebs and even borrowed the '[Mastering CMake](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1930934319)' book from a friend, but I'm still having the hardest time... A lot of stuff exists online with regards to CMake, Fortran, and MinGW, and even combinations of two at a time. But all three together seem to be almost non-existent.

All I want to do (at this point) is get a simple Fortran program built and compiling using CMake on Windows, using MinGW's gfortran compiler.

...And I'm a CMake n00b.

This is what I've been working with so far:

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
project(cmake_test Fortran)
add_executable(testf test.f90)
```

**test.f90:**

```
      program test
      write(*,*)"hello world"
      endprogram test
```

I've got the MSYS2 version of MinGW, since that's the only version that the code I'm eventually going to be compiling will compile with on Windows. (Ie. when I compile it with my own Makefile in the MSYS2 shell, it compiles.)

I've got my Windows Path appended with `;C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`. (I've also tried `;C:\msys64\usr\bin`, but it complains about `sh.exe` being in the same directory, among other issues.)

Then I pop open the CMake-GUI, load in the CMakeLists above, hit Configure, specify the generator for the project to be "MinGW Makefiles", select "Use default native compilers", and get the following output:

```
The Fortran compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
Check for working Fortran compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gfortran.exe
Check for working Fortran compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gfortran.exe  -- works
Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info
Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info - done
Checking whether C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gfortran.exe supports Fortran 90
Checking whether C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gfortran.exe supports Fortran 90 -- yes
Configuring done
```

Then I click Configure again and get:

```
Configuring done
```

Then Generate:

```
Generating done
```

In my build directory there is then a Makefile and a number of other files and directories.

I try running make in the MSYS2 shell, and I get this:

```
myself@COMPUTER MSYS /c/users/myself/desktop/dll_test/with_fortran_cmake/build
$ make
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\users\myself\desktop\dll_test\with_fortran_cmake\build>
```

That last line is a prompt. If I type stuff like `make` it seems to run it again and it just brings up the prompt again, within the prompt. If I hit Ctrl+C, it kills it and returns to the normal MSYS2 prompt.

So I can't figure out how to actually make it, assuming I'm even doing the CMake part right.

**Question: How do I get this example code to build/compile/run given the constraints I've listed?**

(What I'd actually rather do, once I get past this part, is get it to work with Visual Studio 13, since I have a C++ project being built with CMake (written mostly by someone else to whom I have limited access for questions and aid) from which I want to be able to call my Fortran. Once I get the Fortran into a library of some sort which is callable by the C++ from Visual Studio, the Fortran can pretty much just be left alone as a pre-built library. I know that editing Fortran from VS is not really much of a possibility, and I'm not interested in doing it.)

Here are the contents of the generated **`Makefile`** (note my editor replaced tabs with spaces when I copied it here):

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "MinGW Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.5

# Default target executed when no arguments are given to make.
default_target: all

.PHONY : default_target

# Allow only one "make -f Makefile2" at a time, but pass parallelism.
.NOTPARALLEL:


#=============================================================================
# Special targets provided by cmake.

# Disable implicit rules so canonical targets will work.
.SUFFIXES:


# Remove some rules from gmake that .SUFFIXES does not remove.
SUFFIXES =

.SUFFIXES: .hpux_make_needs_suffix_list


# Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:


# A target that is always out of date.
cmake_force:

.PHONY : cmake_force

#=============================================================================
# Set environment variables for the build.

SHELL = cmd.exe

# The CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND = "C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"

# The command to remove a file.
RM = "C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E remove -f

# Escaping for special characters.
EQUALS = =

# The top-level source directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = C:\Users\myself\Desktop\dll_test\with_fortran_cmake

# The top-level build directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = C:\Users\myself\Desktop\dll_test\with_fortran_cmake\build

#=============================================================================
# Targets provided globally by CMake.

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake cache editor..."
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake-gui.exe" -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : edit_cache

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache/fast: edit_cache

.PHONY : edit_cache/fast

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake to regenerate build system..."
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : rebuild_cache

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache/fast: rebuild_cache

.PHONY : rebuild_cache/fast

# The main all target
all: cmake_check_build_system
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start C:\Users\myself\Desktop\dll_test\with_fortran_cmake\build\CMakeFiles C:\Users\myself\Desktop\dll_test\with_fortran_cmake\build\CMakeFiles\progress.marks
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 all
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start C:\Users\myself\Desktop\dll_test\with_fortran_cmake\build\CMakeFiles 0
.PHONY : all

# The main clean target
clean:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 clean
.PHONY : clean

# The main clean target
clean/fast: clean

.PHONY : clean/fast

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall: all
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall/fast

# clear depends
depend:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 1
.PHONY : depend

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named testf

# Build rule for target.
testf: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 testf
.PHONY : testf

# fast build rule for target.
testf/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\testf.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/testf.dir/build
.PHONY : testf/fast

test.obj: test.f90.obj

.PHONY : test.obj

# target to build an object file
test.f90.obj:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\testf.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/testf.dir/test.f90.obj
.PHONY : test.f90.obj

test.i: test.f90.i

.PHONY : test.i

# target to preprocess a source file
test.f90.i:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\testf.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/testf.dir/test.f90.i
.PHONY : test.f90.i

test.s: test.f90.s

.PHONY : test.s

# target to generate assembly for a file
test.f90.s:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\testf.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/testf.dir/test.f90.s
.PHONY : test.f90.s

# Help Target
help:
    @echo The following are some of the valid targets for this Makefile:
    @echo ... all (the default if no target is provided)
    @echo ... clean
    @echo ... depend
    @echo ... testf
    @echo ... edit_cache
    @echo ... rebuild_cache
    @echo ... test.obj
    @echo ... test.i
    @echo ... test.s
.PHONY : help



#=============================================================================
# Special targets to cleanup operation of make.

# Special rule to run CMake to check the build system integrity.
# No rule that depends on this can have commands that come from listfiles
# because they might be regenerated.
cmake_check_build_system:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
.PHONY : cmake_check_build_system
```

**Version information:**

- GNU Fortran (GCC) 5.3.0
- Windows 7 Enterprise
- Cmake 3.5.2
- MSYS2 - I'm not sure how to find the version for this
- MinGW - I'm not sure how to find the version for this

I've been through a lot of different pages online during my search, and I didn't bother keeping track of them all, but this one in particular is one I keep coming across because it seems like it's very related from the title, but the actual issue and resolution are totally not:

- [How can I get a basic Fortran file to compile on Windows/MinGW using CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36831026/how-can-i-get-a-basic-fortran-file-to-compile-on-windows-mingw-using-cmake)

Comment: You should try using the "MSYS Makefiles" generator instead; that's what I always use when I am using CMake and MSYS2.  Let me know if that does not work.

Comment: Doh! I missed that option! ...However, when I try that and hit Configure:

Comment: `CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MSYS Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.`
`CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MSYS Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.`
`CMake Error: CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage`
`CMake Error: CMAKE_AR was not found, please set to archive program. 
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!`

Comment: Searching around I found: https://github.com/tpaviot/oce/issues/578
But the solution given here is, oddly enough, "use MinGW Makefiles". Not helpful.

Comment: Hooray! I got it working! I'll post the solution in a second. Credit really goes to you though, @DavidGrayson. Thank you!

Comment: Hm, actually... it seems to be using g95 instead of gfortran... Checking into your solution below now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick shell session showing how I was able to build your Fortran program using MSYS2, cmake, make, and gfortran.  You should try running the same commands that I did and see if they give different outputs then investigate the reason.

The MSYSTEM variable is especially important; it is determined by what shortcut you click on when starting MSYS2.

```
$ echo $MSYSTEM
MINGW64

$ which cmake
/mingw64/bin/cmake

$ which gfortran
/mingw64/bin/gfortran

$ which make
/usr/bin/make

$ ls
CMakeLists.txt  test.f90

$ cat CMakeLists.txt
project(cmake_test Fortran)
add_executable(testf test.f90)

$ cat test.f90
      program test
      write(*,*)"hello world"
      endprogram test

$ mkdir build && cd build

$ cmake -G"MSYS Makefiles" ..
-- The Fortran compiler identification is GNU 6.2.0
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: D:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gfortran.exe
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: D:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gfortran.exe  -- works
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info - done
-- Checking whether D:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gfortran.exe supports Fortran 90
-- Checking whether D:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gfortran.exe supports Fortran 90 -- yes
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/david/Documents/scraps/test_fortran/build

$ make
Scanning dependencies of target testf
[ 50%] Building Fortran object CMakeFiles/testf.dir/test.f90.obj
[100%] Linking Fortran executable testf.exe
[100%] Built target testf

$ ./testf.exe
 hello world
```

Comment: Some important differences...

`$ echo $MSYSTEM`
`MSYS`

and

`$ which cmake`
`which: no cmake in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl)`

and

`$ which gfortran`
`/usr/bin/gfortran`

Comment: Which shortcut should I be clicking? Generally I run `C:\msys64\msys2.exe`

Comment: Try running mingw32.exe or mingw64.exe, depending on whether you want a 32-bit or 64-bit executable.  Or find the "MinGW-w64 Win32 Shell" or "MinGW-w64 Win64 Shell" shortcuts in your Start Menu.  Since you are trying to integrate with Visual Studio, you almost certainly do not want the MSYS2 shell (msys2.exe); you want to build a native Windows executable instead.

Comment: I clicked the "MinGW-w64 Win64 Shell" shortcut in my Start Menu, and got the following in the prompt: `'C:\msys64\mingw64_shell.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` (And indeed, that file does not exist in that directory...) Can you explain why is it that I don't want the MSYS2 shell? Why will that be an issue with Visual Studio?

Comment: Cam you try mingw64.exe instead?  That shortcut was purposely broken by the MSYS2 maintainers when they updated the filesystem package.  The "MSYS2 shell" is for running or building programs that depend on the POSIX emulation layer msys-2.0.dll (Cygwin) which is very different from the runtime environment of Visual Studio programs.

Comment: Hm. Well I tried mingw64.exe, and got closer to your results, but I still have `which cmake` yielding `which: no cmake in (/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl)`

Comment: Also, I really would rather be doing this from the CMake-GUI, since the software I'm going to be integrating with is always built that way. I'd rather not have to make the instructions for users much different or more complicated by adding other steps like "Now open a MinGW terminal and type..."

Comment: Honestly, I'm not such a guru with a lot of this stuff. I'm more of an algorithms guy, and I often get bogged down by Operating System stuff and other particulars which I could care less about and don't really understand. The short version of the slightly longer story is that I've got a C++ program someone created and is being built and used on Windows, using Visual Studio and CMake-GUI. Then I've got a Fortran library written for and on Linux which I've been told to merge into the C++ program, so that it'll be callable from there.

Comment: So I've been trying to get the Fortran to compile on Windows (which I've done with MSYS2), via the CMake-GUI (working on that now), such that it'll be incorporatable into the C++ program (still work to do on that end with the API and all). Are you saying I'm going the completely wrong direction?

Comment: Let's use the cmake command now instead of the GUI, because it is way easier to communicate about.  For an example of the easy communication, look at my answer where I was able to unambiguously show you exactly what command to command to run and exactly what results you should see.  Compare that to your question, where you tried to describe various interactive user actions in the GUI, but fully describing the ouput would involve taking a video of your screen.  It should be straightforward to switch the GUI later.

Comment: I don't want to talk about integrating with C++ yet or this question will be come to broad.  I would suggest you try using the MSYS2 g++ compiler instead of Visual Studio since that is more likely to work (mixing binaries from different toolchains is iffy and adds more complexity for your users).  You can ask another question with the "msys2" tag, which I monitor.

Comment: Since your /mingw64/bin/cmake is missing, you need to install it by running `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake`.

Comment: You should click the triangle to upvote my answer and click the check mark to accept it if it works for you.

Comment: Fair enough about not using the gui. ;) Also, I brought up the C++ stuff to explain more of why I was going this route, but you're right it's not necessarily immediately relevant. I installed `/mingw64/bin/cmake` as you instructed, and then reran the commands above in mingw64.exe, and it worked... except that it's using f95 instead of gfortran, just as was happening in the gui. I'm assuming I can fix it by setting a commandline environment variable as I did in the gui solution, but why doesn't yours need that?

Comment: Also, as for upvoting and accepting-- I actually upvoted it a while ago, but got this message: `Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.` Also, I haven't accepted your solution yet since it's still not completely working for me. I will when we get there! ;)

Comment: My guess would be that you installed the f95 package and I did not, and that's why we get different results.  You should probably modify the CMake command to be like this to force it to pick the right compiler: `cmake -G"MSYS Makefiles" -DCMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER=$MSYSTEM_PREFIX/bin/gfortran.exe ..`

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: There IS a working solution here -- read till the end!**

Thanks to David Grayson's comment on the original question, I've found a partial solution. "Partial" because it uses f95 instead of gfortran. I'm posting it because it might work for someone else, and if I'm able to figure out how to get it to work with gfortran, I'll just update it.

Turns out the main issue was a pretty simple mistake: I was using "MinGW Makefiles" instad of "MSYS Makefiles".

When I only changed that, however, I got the following output in the CMake-GUI when I clicked Configure:

```
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MSYS Makefiles". CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set. You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MSYS Makefiles". CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set. You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_AR was not found, please set to archive program. Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

To fix this, I changed my Windows Path again. I'd been using `;C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`, and so I switched it to `;C:\msys64\usr\bin`.

This then worked (I clicked Configure a second time, clicked Generate, and then ran `make` via the MSYS2 terminal in the `/build` directory), but as you can see in the following output, it used f95 instead of gfortran:

```
The Fortran compiler identification is GNU 5.3.0
Check for working Fortran compiler: C:/msys64/usr/bin/f95.exe
Check for working Fortran compiler: C:/msys64/usr/bin/f95.exe  -- works
Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info
Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info - done
Checking whether C:/msys64/usr/bin/f95.exe supports Fortran 90
Checking whether C:/msys64/usr/bin/f95.exe supports Fortran 90 -- yes
Configuring done
```

I'm still working to get it to use gfortran, and I'll update this solution if I figure it out.

**Edit:**

Okay, this is obviously more of a hack and I'm sure that there's a better solution. I renamed `C:\msys64\usr\bin\f95.exe` to something else (so that MSYS2 wouldn't find it as another Fortran compiler before finding gfortran). I also had to clear CMake's cache and restart it. But now it works:

```
The Fortran compiler identification is GNU 5.3.0
Check for working Fortran compiler: C:/msys64/usr/bin/gfortran.exe
Check for working Fortran compiler: C:/msys64/usr/bin/gfortran.exe  -- works
Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info
Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info - done
Checking whether C:/msys64/usr/bin/gfortran.exe supports Fortran 90
Checking whether C:/msys64/usr/bin/gfortran.exe supports Fortran 90 -- yes
Configuring done
```

Working on figuring out how to do this the "correct" way.

**Edit:**

Okay, I'm guessing this is the more proper way to do it, as I assume it essentially does the same thing as setting environment variables on the commandline when calling CMake from there.

In the CMake-GUI, I set everything up as explained before, but before clicking Configure for the first time, I clicked the "Add Entry" button with the little plus symbol. I then set two new Cache Entries -- though only one is really necessary:

```
Name: CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER
Type: FILEPATH
Value: C:\msys64\usr\bin\gfortran.exe
```

I also set the following, but this was only to verify that it was calling gfortran properly, as you'll see in the output below:

```
Name: CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE
Type: BOOL
Value: [True]
```

Then, running `make` in the MSYS2 terminal, I got the following:

```
$ make
"/C/Program Files (x86)/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" -H/C/Users/myself/Desktop/dll_test/with_fortran_cmake -B/C/Users/myself/Desktop/dll_test/with_fortran_cmake/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
"/C/Program Files (x86)/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_start /C/Users/myself/Desktop/dll_test/with_fortran_cmake/build/CMakeFiles /C/Users/myself/Desktop/dll_test/with_fortran_cmake/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/c/Users/myself/Desktop/dll_test/with_fortran_cmake/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/testf.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/testf.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/c/Users/myself/Desktop/dll_test/with_fortran_cmake/build'
"/C/Program Files (x86)/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "MSYS Makefiles" /C/Users/myself/Desktop/dll_test/with_fortran_cmake /C/Users/myself/Desktop/dll_test/with_fortran_cmake /C/Users/myself/Desktop/dll_test/with_fortran_cmake/build /C/Users/myself/Desktop/dll_test/with_fortran_cmake/build /C/Users/myself/Desktop/dll_test/with_fortran_cmake/build/CMakeFiles/testf.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Scanning dependencies of target testf
make[2]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/myself/Desktop/dll_test/with_fortran_cmake/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/testf.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/testf.dir/requires
make[2]: Entering directory '/c/Users/myself/Desktop/dll_test/with_fortran_cmake/build'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'CMakeFiles/testf.dir/requires'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/myself/Desktop/dll_test/with_fortran_cmake/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/testf.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/testf.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/c/Users/myself/Desktop/dll_test/with_fortran_cmake/build'
[ 50%] Building Fortran object CMakeFiles/testf.dir/test.f90.obj
/C/msys64/usr/bin/gfortran.exe     -c /C/Users/myself/Desktop/dll_test/with_fortran_cmake/test.f90 -o CMakeFiles/testf.dir/test.f90.obj
[100%] Linking Fortran executable testf.exe
"/C/Program Files (x86)/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" -E remove -f CMakeFiles/testf.dir/objects.a
/C/msys64/usr/bin/ar.exe cr CMakeFiles/testf.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles/testf.dir/objects1.rsp
/C/msys64/usr/bin/gfortran.exe     -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles/testf.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o testf.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libtestf.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0
make[2]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/myself/Desktop/dll_test/with_fortran_cmake/build'
[100%] Built target testf
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/myself/Desktop/dll_test/with_fortran_cmake/build'
"/C/Program Files (x86)/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_start /C/Users/myself/Desktop/dll_test/with_fortran_cmake/build/CMakeFiles 0
```

And the resulting program works both via the MSYS2 terminal and a Windows command prompt.

...Now I need to figure out how to get this all together with C++ in Visual Studio. Stay tuned for more SO questions! :D

Comment: If you run cmake-gui, I'd suggest running cmake-gui from an MSYS2/MinGW shell so it has the right PATH already set up; no need to edit your Windows environment variables using the Microsoft interface.

Comment: Also, since you compiled an executable that depends on the msys-2.0.dll POSIX emulation layer, I am pretty skeptical of integrating it with Visual Studio, which uses the Microsoft Visual C runtime (msvcrt*.dll).

Comment: Got it. I'm running cmake-gui from the Start Menu shortcut because that's how the C++ code I'm aiming at integrating with is typically run. I can't really tell people "When you build this part, you need to first open a command prompt..." Do you have a suggestion for how better to get it to integrate with Visual Studio?

Comment: Rather... a suggestion for how to go about building it such that I'll be better setup for it to integrate with Visual Studio, once I reach that point.